# Custom TableViewCell value disappear when scrolling up

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, custom-controls

before i ask this question i searched a lot and see a few answer, but none of them could help me, so i decide to ask it again,... thanks for any help

i understand there are two way to solve this problem, one is to store tableviewcell value in array and the other is to avoid reuse it, but i could n t implement them,

i have custome tableviewcell which has one textfield inside and a button, when a button clicked a add another tableviewcell at the bottom of tableview;

when i implementing the first solution i get the tableviewcell from textfield.supperview like this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"TextFileld Value : %@" , textField.text);

    DivideTableViewCell *cell = (DivideTableViewCell *)textField.superview;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [uiTableView indexPathForCell:cell]; 

    NSLog(@"index Path %i" , indexPath.row);
}
```

but every time the indexPath.row is 0 and i could nt update my datasource array ....

and also unfortunately i couldn't implement the second solution too...

So thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store the TableViewCells try the following.

Have an NSMutableDictionary instance variable and alloc/init it in the TableViewController's init method (don't forget to release it in the dealloc).

```
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    ivarDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  DivideTableViewCell *cell = [ivarDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[DivideTableViewCell alloc] init];
    [iverDictionary setObject:cell forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    // Cell setup 1
  }

  // Cell setup 2

  return cell;
}
```

From there you could setup all you need for the cell in Setup 1 area, or if you want to do some setup each time the cell will be recalled then use Setup 2.

Please note this is not a great idea in terms of minimising memory usage, I would not use this method for anything with more then 20-30 cells.

You will still need to use the TextField delegate methods to pull out the entered text, you might also want parse the indexPath variable to each cell when it is created so you can know which textfield is being edited as well.

Comment: I think this probably leaks memory on the cells, you might need to add an autorelease to the DivideTableViewCell alloc/init line

Comment: hi thanks for your attention, but unfortunately it does n t work for me , i don't know where i am doing something wrong, lets change the target, i can get the text from textFieldDidEndEditing, how can i get the index path for that tableviewcell which textfielld value changed???
i think if i can get correct index path i can make my array datasource update and everything will be ok.

   
so thanks

Comment: @ali you will need to add an ivar to your DivideTableViewCell that records the row it is being displayed for. Make sure you update this value each time the cell is presented with tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0):

```
I  Think you should store all the values of the text field in an array and replace with the changed value every time like i did,see my code ,
```

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
  {
  CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
      NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
      for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
      {
          if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
          {
              cell =  (CustomCell *) currentObject;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  cell.capitalLabel.text =[capitals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.stateLabel.text = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.t1.delegate=self;
  cell.t1.tag=indexPath.row;
  cell.t1.text=[arrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.s1.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
  cell.s1.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1000, 40);
  return cell;
  }
  }
  /*-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
  {
  [arrTemp replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
  }
  */
  -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  [arrTemp replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
  }